# How to add image in place of text in navigation bar?

Tags: iphone

How to add image in place of text in navigation bar ?

Comment: this    @implementation  UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TabBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end

Comment: this adds the image to whole naviation bar

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `titleView` property of the `UINavigationItem` ?

Answer (score 0):

[UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) is a subclass of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/). Thus, you can create your UIImageView object and add it as a subview in your UINavigation bar.

[navigationBar addSubview:imageView];

One thing you need to keep in mind that the navigationbar dimensions which is 320X44 in Portrait & 480X20 points in landscape for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

u can create an image view with some image and add it to the title view of navigation bar

like:--

self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView;

Comment: you can put in particular view did load for differnt images or put them in delegate class where u unitialized navigation controller for the first time to show that image on whole project